# integers displayed instead of a sorted string

Tags: c

i want to sort a string using counting sort but instead of a sorted string some integer values are displayed with a warning `iteration 254u invokes undefined behavior` pointing at the expression `c[i]+=c[i-1]` even though the iterations  doesn't seem to exceed the signed int limit

the code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define range 255
void count_sort(char arr[],int n)
{
    int c[range];
    int i;
    memset(c,0,sizeof(c));
    char b[strlen(arr)];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ++c[arr[i]];
    }
    for(i=1;i<=range;++i)
    {
        c[i]+=c[i-1];
    }
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;--i)
    {
        b[c[arr[i]]-1]=arr[i];
        --c[arr[i]];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=b[i];
    }
}
void print(char arr[],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    char arr[]="november";
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    count_sort(arr,n);
    print(arr,n);
    return 0;
}
```

what changes are required to make the code run correctly

Comment: You are printing the integer values: `printf("%d ",arr[i]);`. Use `%c` for characters.

Comment: `b`, `c` aren't great variable names. Makes your code quite hard to follow. Suggest using more meaningful names.

Comment: [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub): `for ( i = 1; i <= range; ++i )` -> `i <= range`. The array is declared as `int c[range];`. In the loop, it's causing out-of-bounds access, hence UB.

Answer (score 1):

I checked you here [link](https://www.onlinegdb.com/). The code is correct except for the lines below

```
(1) printf("%d ",arr[i]); 
Change this line to the following since you are printing characters and not integers.
printf("%c ",arr[i]);
```

If you keep %d then you are casting the char to an integer, and you'll get the ascii value. So for %d specifier, you will get a sorted array of integer values which are ascii values for the corresponding characters.

```
(2) int c[range]; 
   Change the line to the following 
   int c[range+1];
```

Now in your second for loop, it will not exceed the bounds of the array `c` and you will not get the undefined behavior.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No the rest of the code is not correct. Like @Azeem pointed out the second `for`-loop of `count_sort` will exceed the bounds of the array `c`

Comment: @Ackdari With the second change, this problem will also get sort out. Thanks for pointing out that part.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points that I'd like to share:

You're using `%d` as format specifier in `printf()` in `print` function so change that to `%c` like this:

```
printf("%c ", arr[i]);
```

If your string is properly `\0` terminated and you can do without printing space between characters then you can directly use `printf()` with `%s` it:

```
printf("%s", arr);
```

You don't need the custom `print()` function in this case.

---

This loop

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= range; ++i ) // <== out-of-bounds
{
    c[i] += c[i-1];
}
```

is causing out-of-bounds access resulting in [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). As `range` represents `255` but the loop condition is `i <= range` whereas it should be `i < range` to keep the iterations in the valid range i.e. 0-254.

---

You are calculating the length of the string like this:

```
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

`sizeof` also calculates the terminating '\0' character so the length of the string will be:

```
sizeof( arr )    = 9
sizeof( arr[0] ) = 1

n = 9 / 1 = 9
```

But, the length of the string `november` is `8`. `strlen()` would be a better choice here.

```
int n = strlen( arr );
```

Or,

```
int n = sizeof( arr ) - 1;     // don't include `\0`
```

---

In the `count_sort` function, you're declaring the array`c` like this:

```
int c[range];
```

And, then using `memset` to set it. You could initialize it like this:

```
int c[range] = {0};
```

More on `memset` [here](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0360/).

---

The array `b` is declared like this:

```
char b[strlen(arr)];
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But, you already have `n`, use that. You don't need to calculate the length again.

---

Answer (score 0):

there are some problem in you code first you are using wrong format specifier for printing chars.You have to use `%c` instead of `%d` in your printing function.

also you should remove `=` from this loop `for(i=1;i<=range;++i)` , otherwise you will pass boundaries of array `c` which will lead to undefined behavior , or if you need that element you should declare `c[range+1]` instead of `c[range]`.

also note that in your sorting since ASCII code of `\0` is smallest , it will become first element of your array and so neither `b` nor `arr` will be terminated.
I suggest this loop:

```
    for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        b[c[arr[i]] - 2] = arr[i];
        --c[arr[i]];
    }
    b[n-1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use %c instead of %d to print the characters.
2. You should also use for( i=1; i < range; i++ ), i <= range will give fault as last index of array is range-1.

Comment: Be beware that OP is also using `c[i-1]` to address the array, so starting with `i = 0` will also result in undefined behavior